# How to show additional info on selected day using jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery's Datepicker for a textbox as below. I have restricted the days a user is allowed to select but my question is if there is a way to have a special text appeared in the textbox along with each selected date.

For example, if a user selects day number 1, then there is shown **Monday, 19 September 2011** How to make it **Monday, 19 September 2011 and a special name for the Monday here?**

The same goes for all the available to select days like **Tuesday, 20 September 2011 and a special name for the Tuesday here?**

Thank you for this

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var date = new Date();
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(y, m, d),
        dateFormat: 'DD, d MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
        var day = date.getDay(); 
        return [day == 1 || day == 4 || day == 5,""];
        }
});

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "el" ] );

});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this array:

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunny Sunday";
weekday[1]="Manic Monday";
weekday[2]="Terrible Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wild Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thorny Thursday";
weekday[5]="Freaky Friday";
weekday[6]="Sadistic Saturday";
```

Then add this method:

```
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var day = new Date(dateText).getDay();
        $(this).val(dateText + ': ' + weekday[day]);
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Xm6Dm/

Comment: Thanks for this but I want a different text for each different date...  It will be a manually but it is ok.

Comment: Is there a reason why I get "undefined" as the special text in Wordpress?

Comment: Did you forget to add that array? It might not have scope to that `var weekday = new Array(7)...`. Check where you're declaring that variable.

Comment: It's actually a little overcast this past Sunday. -1

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the [`dayNamesShort`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dayNamesShort) option, if you do not intend to use the default ones. That way, you can simply configure it in your `dateFormat`:

```
var myWeekdays = "Sunny Manic Terrible Wild Thorny Freaky Sadistic".split(' ');

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    ...
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM yy (D)',
    dayNamesShort: myWeekdays
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/Xm6Dm/2/.